# In which version of Windows is PowerShell installed by default?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, powershell

I just installed XP SP2 and I was expecting to have PowerShell 1.0 installed; however, it isn't.

It seems I have to manually install it. If I upgrade to SP3 do I get PowerShell.

[From Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

---

> PowerShell 1.0 was released in 2006 for Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista. It is an optional component of Windows Server 2008.
>
> PowerShell 2.0 is integrated with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and is released for Windows XP with Service Pack 3, Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2, and Windows Vista with Service Pack 1.

---

It seems PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0 doesn't get installed by default in XP SP3, 2003 and Vista.

I can't find any concrete information can someone confirm this please.

Comment: Why are you still installing XP...SP2?!

Comment: "Powershell doesn't ship as part of the operating system prior to Windows 7" - is that concrete enough for you?

Comment: Guys, asking which version of Windows comes with PowerShell installed is a perfectly on-topic question that's relevant to professional systems administration.  It may be a lazy question that deserves some downvotes, but it's not an off-topic question.

Comment: @NathanC, maybe he wants to make tests with software for compatibility, maybe he wants to test operating system features, or security features, or maybe just making some kind of research, or just for curiosity. In production environment everywhere, even after 4 years of your "not helpful" question, there are still millions of companies that use windows XP. Did i answer your question? Try to make useful comments and not useless ones. Mine is useful, because it will prevent similar comments in the future...

Answer (score 15):

[Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 are the first Windows versions to come with PowerShell installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637750%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), by default.

> Windows PowerShell 2.0 needs to be installed on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista only. It is already installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Ignoring the horribleness of installing XP SP2 in this day and age, if not having PowerShell installed by default is a problem, you have many options to correct that, both retroactively (like GPOs or startup/logon scripts to install it) and going forward (by slipstreaming it into an ISO image or a machine that you deploy).

Comment: your reference link is outdated

Answer (score 8):

### Short answer

As already given: Windows XP doesn't come with PowerShell integrated, so your specific solution is to install PS1 on WinXP SP2 assuming the availability of the software.

### Long answer

Reading the dedicated section [PowerShell #Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#Versions) on Wikipedia gave me the following information. I stripped details and most of the (reliable and informative) for this overview:

#### Windows PowerShell Versions

| Version | integrated with | released for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 |  | Windows XP SP2 Server 2003 SP1 Windows Vista |
| 2.0 | Windows 7 Windows Server 2008 R2[59] | Windows XP SP3 Windows Server 2003 SP2 Windows Vista SP1 |
| 3.0 | Windows 8 Windows Server 2012 | Windows 7 SP1 Windows Server 2008 SP1 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 |
| 4.0 | Windows 8.1 Windows Server 2012 R2 | Windows 7 SP1 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Windows Server 2012 |
| 5.1 | Windows 10 Anniversary Update Windows Server 2016 | Windows 7 Windows Server 2008 Windows Server 2008 R2 Windows Server 2012 Windows Server 2012 R2 |

#### PowerShell Core 6

PowerShell Core 6 is the first free, cross-plattform implementation of PoweShell (Note the missing *Windows* and the additional *Core* in the name)

- [PowerShell is Microsoft’s latest open source release, coming to Linux, OS X | Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/08/powershell-is-microsofts-latest-open-source-release-coming-to-linux-os-x/)
- [PowerShell Core 6.0: Generally Available (GA) and Supported! | PowerShell Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/)

#### PowerShell 7

PowerShell 7 replaces PowerShell Core 6.x products and Windows PowerShell 5.1 with focus on becoming a viable replacement for PS 5.1. The *Core* part in the name was removed to reflect the join.

- [PowerShell 7 Roadmap | PowerShell Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-road-map/)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is not installed with Windows XP. You have to manually install it afterwards.